# Force rows in HTML table to go up to table border without using colspan

Tags: html, html-table

I have an html table where the widths of `td` elements are specified as percentages of the width of the table.  However, its rows contain different numbers of `td` elements (see below toy example).  The result is that rows with fewer `td` elements do not reach the right border of the table -- there's a gap at the end and the column widths are displayed incorrectly.  Is it possible to fix this, without using `colspan`?  Basically, I just want rows to go right up to the table border and the cells they contain to have the boundaries as specified by their percentage widths.  I want to avoid `colspan` because I fear in general it could become quite complex and my problem conceptually is straightforward.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table border="1" width="100pt">
   <tr>
    <td width="25%">
     A1
    </td>
    <td width="75%">
     A2
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      B1
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

This gives me

[image]

But what I want is:

[image]

Comment: You can't, you should use `colspan` - that's why it's there - the only way you can is to have each row as a separate table, but that will get messy and will prevent cols lining up properly forcing you to do a ton of css, which will then increase complexity even more. Use `colspan`

Comment: That you want to avoid colspan due to layout issues suggests the data isn't tabular, so a table is maybe not the right choice. Have you looked at something like CSS flexbox?

Comment: The tables I am looking at come from a docx file and the tables can be quite complex with lots of merged cells (e.g. column headers spanning multiple columns) but it is definitely tabular data.

Comment: Looks like my best bet is to find the coarsest grid over the whole table that contains all cell boundaries then from that get the `colspan`s.  That's pretty straightforward and should work for all possible cases.